# Quelle est la différence entre « pas de » et « aucun » ?

Tags: grammaire, expressions, négation

Quelle est la différence entre « pas de » et « aucun » ? Par exemple:

> Il n'y a pas de doute que ...
>
> Il n'y a aucun doute que ...

Comment: Dans ce cas-ci, les deux expressions semblent être tout à fait synonymes. Donc aucune différence à mon sens :-)

Answer (score 3):

il n'y a pas de différence dans le sens. "Aucun" permet d'insister davantage que "pas de"

Answer (score -1):

Il est diffèrent dans le sens qui "pas de" exprime qui le sujet n'ai pas de quelque chose, alors que "aucun" exprimez qui le sujet avait ça dans le passé, mais n'ai pas plus maintenant. Ma pensée est correcte?

Comment: Il me semble que ton analyse serait juste si tu comparais *pas de* avec *plus aucun*. Mais le contraire serait possible, *plus de* et *aucun*, où seule la première expression permet de comprendre qu'on décrit une possession "perdue". Et donc non, cette distinction n'est pas présente par défaut dans les termes *pas de* et *aucun*.